# Error: Could not connect to the server | Apollo Error

Tags: next.js, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am experiencing this weird error in Apollo that I am unable to fix. Any help is greatly appreciated!

So the issue is that Apollo works just fine when I load the webpage from my laptop but problems start when I load the webpage from my phone. The error is as follows:
[image]

Here is the full error from the console on the phone.
[image]

I also have a custom apollo client setup as mentioned in this page: https://www.apollographql.com/blog/building-a-next-js-app-with-apollo-client-slash-graphql/

It's similar to the one below:

```
import { useMemo } from "react";
import {
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloClient,
  HttpLink,
  NormalizedCacheObject,
} from "@apollo/client";

let apolloClient: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>;

const createApolloClient = () => {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === "undefined",
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: process.env.API_ENDPOINT,
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
};

export function initializeApollo(initialState: object | null = null) {

  const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient();

  // If your page has Next.js data fetching methods that use Apollo Client,
  // the initial state gets hydrated here
  if (initialState) {
    // Get existing cache, loaded during client side data fetching
    const existingCache = _apolloClient.extract();

    // Restore the cache using the data passed from
    // getStaticProps/getServerSideProps combined with the existing cached data
    _apolloClient.cache.restore({ ...existingCache, ...initialState });
  }

  // For SSG and SSR always create a new Apollo Client
  if (typeof window === "undefined") return _apolloClient;

  // Create the Apollo Client once in the client
  if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient;

  return _apolloClient;
}

export function useApollo(initialState: object) {
  const store = useMemo(() => initializeApollo(initialState), [initialState]);

  return store;
}
```

Comment: If it works on your Laptop and the url is the same on mobile then I guess your phone has some kind of Firewall which blocks the server? Just an educated guess. Your config looks fine.

Comment: Well I actually don’t know about that. I tired it on safari and edge as of now. And the device that I used it on was on a jailbroken iPhone 8+. Btw I did also try it on an ipad and the issue still persists. The only device left to test it on is an android device for now.

Comment: Test it on Android. Apple is the kind of company which builds strange checks into their products.

Comment: Aight I’ll try it on an android